# numpy: broadcasting into multiple inner products and inverses

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse, broadcasting, inner-product

I have arrays `e`, (shape `q` by `l`) `f` (shape `n` by `l`), and `w` (shape `n` by `l`), and I want to create an array `M` where `M[s,i,j] = np.sum(w[s, :] * e[i, :] * e[j, :])`, and an array `F`, where `F[s,j] = np.sum(w[s, :] * f[s, :] * e[j, :])`.

Both are easy enough to do by, for instance, looping through elements of `M`, but I want to be more efficient (my real data has something like 1M entries of length 5k). For `F`, I can use `F = np.inner(w * f, e)` (which I verified produces the same answer as the loop). `M` is more difficult, so the first step is to loop through dimension zero of with a list comprehension, saying that `M = np.stack([np.inner(r[:] * e, e) for r in w])`  (I have verified this also works the same as the loop). `np.inner()` doesn't take any axes arguments, so it's not clear to me how to tell the arrays to just broadcast over all rows of `w`.

Finally, I need to use elements of `M` and `F` to create a matrix `A`, where `A[s,i] = np.sum(np.linalg.inv(M[s, :, :])[i, :] * F[i, :])`. This also looks inner-product-ish, but taking lots of individual inverses is time-consuming, so is there a way to compute inverses of slices, short of looping?

Some test values in my arrays are as follows:

```
e = array([[-0.9840087 , -0.17812043],
           [ 0.17812043, -0.9840087 ]])

w = array([[  1.12545297e+01,   1.48690140e+02],
           [  7.30718244e+00,   4.07840612e+02],
           [  2.62753065e+02,   2.27085711e+02],
           [  1.53045364e+01,   5.63025281e+02],
           [  8.00555079e+00,   2.16207407e+02],
           [  1.54070190e+01,   1.87213209e+06],
           [  2.71802081e+01,   1.06392902e+02],
           [  3.46300255e+01,   1.29404438e+03],
           [  7.77638140e+00,   4.18759293e+03],
           [  1.12874849e+01,   5.75023379e+02]])

f = array([[ 0.48907404,  0.06111084],
           [-0.21899297, -0.02207311],
           [ 0.58688524,  0.05156326],
           [ 0.57407751,  0.10004592],
           [ 0.94172351,  0.03895357],
           [-0.7489003 , -0.08911183],
           [-0.7043736 , -0.19014227],
           [ 0.58950925,  0.16587887],
           [-0.35557142, -0.14530267],
           [ 0.24548714,  0.03221844]])
```

Comment: In `M[s,i,j] = np.sum(w[s] * e[i] * e[j])` what's sum over?  I see `i,j,s` on both sides.  Is it `(w[s,k]*e[i,k]*e[j,k]).sum(axis=k)`?

Comment: `np.einsum` is a quick and easy tool for doing this kind of sum of products.  The `s,i,j` equations almost write themselves.

Comment: rows of `w`, `f`, and `e` are length-`l` vectors, so the element-wise product of the three is summed over its only axis

Comment: Sometimes it is clearer to write `e[j,:]` than just `e[j]`, even if the interpreter treats both the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M[s,i,j] = np.sum(w[s, :] * e[i, :] * e[j, :])
```

translates to

```
M = np.einsum('sk,ik,jk->sij',w,e,e)
```

and

```
F[s,j] = np.sum(w[s, :] * f[s, :] * e[j, :])
F = np.einsum('sk,sk,jk->sj', w, f, e)
```

I haven't tested these with your samples, but the translation is simple enough.

With real large arrays you may have to break the expressions up into pieces.  With 4 iteration variables the overall iteration space can be very big.  But first see if these expressions work with modest sized arrays.

As for

```
A[s,i] = np.sum(np.linalg.inv(M[s, :, :])[i, :] * F[i, :])
```

I looks like `np.linalg.inv(M)` works, performing the `s` i x i inverses

If so then

```
 IM = np.linalg.inv(M)
 A = np.einsum('skm,ik,im->si', IM, F)
```

I'm guessing more here.

Again, dimension might get too large, but try it small first.

Typically linear equation solutions are recommended over direct inverses, something like

```
  A = F/M
  A = np.linalg.solve(M, F)
```

since you probably want `A` such that `M@A=F` (@ matrix product).  But I'm kind of rusty on these matters.  Also check `tensorsolve` and `tensorinv`.

Comment: `A = np.einsum('skm,ik,im->si', IM, F)` has too many indices, but `A = np.linalg.solve(M, F)` produces an array with the correct dimensions, which is half the battle.

Comment: Is 'sij,ij->si` better?

Comment: No, that index adjustment causes an error with the operand broadcasting again `[original->remapped]: (50,2,2)->(50,2,2) (50,2)->(50,2)`. However, with the `np.linalg.solve()` implementation, this method produces the same answer as `f.dot(e.T)` when `w` is everywhere one. This is the expected behavior, so I am pretty sure it works.